# Camera2 Set Fixed Resolution

Tags: java, android-camera2, android-studio-2.3

I am using Camera2 API for my creating camera using Android Studio 2.3.May I ask if it is possible to set a fixed camera resolution into my camera? And if it is possible how can I set a fixed camera resolution? I'm really new to camera2 and android studio. I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use fixed resolution. Only don't run this APK on devices that don't support this camera resolution.

For example,

```
InputConfiguration inputConfiguration = new InputConfiguration(640, 480, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
cameraDevice.createReprocessableCaptureSession(inputConfiguration, outputs, callback, handler);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. But can I ask for help about what function/code should I use in declaring fixed resolution?

Comment: createReprocessableCaptureSession is deprecated :(