# How to pass input configuration to camera 2 android

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am developing an android camera application, and I wanted to pass in the capture size to configure the camera before taking a picture.

This is my code:

```
try {
    mCaptureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

    InputConfiguration inputConfiguration = new InputConfiguration(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.JPEG); //error here.

    cameraDevice.createReprocessableCaptureSession(inputConfiguration, Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, handler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera Preview Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }, null);
}
```

So, I am trying to pass an input configuration to the camera here.
My problem is I'm getting an error on the `InputConfiguration` line.
This is my error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input format 256 is not valid`

I tried this with a lot of different `ImageFormat`s like JPEG, UNKNOWN, NV21 and others. It's not working.
Help me resolve this error and also if my approach is wrong in interacting with the camera do tell me.

Comment: you should first try to get what all camera sizes are available then pass the suitable one into your request

Comment: I actually wrote another code to create a spinner and push in all the valid sizes of the camera using getOutputsizes() and 1920x1080 is supported in my phone I have tested it. But the above code is not working. There seems to be a problem in the Image formats but, did not understand what.

Comment: did you tried with png format ?

Comment: Png is not there in Input Configuration. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat

Answer (score 0):

You are working with TEMPLATE_PREVIEW, which does not support **ImageFormat.JPEG**.

**Camera2** mandates that preview supports [YUV 420](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888), [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48780438/192373):

```
InputConfiguration inputConfiguration = new InputConfiguration(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
```

Comment: Still not working. While I have my TEMPLATE_PREVIEW.         `mCaptureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
              mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);               InputConfiguration inputConfiguration = new InputConfiguration(1920,1080,ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);` and I even added  a test log and YUV_420_888 supports 1920*1080, but still not getting it.

Comment: *'still not getting it'* - what does this mean exactly? The **IllegalArgumentException** is gone, isn't it? Is it "Camera Preview Failed!!" toast?

Comment: No it's not gone still getting the same exception, and this is what I'am using to find the supported sizes on my device:                                                         
 ` Size[] sizes = configurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
                for(Size size : sizes){
                    Log.d("test","width: "+size.getWidth()+" height"+size.getHeight());
                }`  and I'am setting one of these sizes to inputConfiguration and I'am using this object in createReprocessableCaptureSession call. Is my approach correct or not?    @Alex Cohn

Comment: could you post the updated code and few lines of log before exception?

Comment: there is a more detailed question I reposted on: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697534/how-to-configure-the-capture-size-in-camera-2-api], do look at it  and I was wondering if getInputSizes() and getOutputSizes() make any difference. My app is working if i put getInputSize() in InputConfiguration(), but getInputSize() is showing only 1 supported size on my mobile whereas getOutputSize() is showing many.

Answer (score 0):

Input configurations are only used [reprocessing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_PRIVATE_REPROCESSING) use cases, where you have an application-level circular buffer of captured partially processed frames.

When the user hits the shutter button, you send one of the captured frames back to the camera device for final processing.  The input configuration is for selecting the size and format of this path back into the camera.

For simple capture applications, you only care about the output configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Another sad case is described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#REPROCESS_MAX_CAPTURE_STALL

Check that your camera supports reprocessing or you would not pass through "input format is not valid" at all as no input would be allowed for reprocessing.

Also the absence of this key value can signal that Yuv reprocessing is not available: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_YUV_REPROCESSING