# How to configure the capture size in Camera 2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm making an android camera application. My doubt is how do I pass the supported resolutions as parameters to the camera.

So, first I'm getting all the supported resolution sizes:

```
Size[] sizes = configurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
Log.d("test","size:"+sizes.length);

for(Size size : sizes){
    Log.d("test", "width: " + size.getWidth() + " height" + size.getHeight());
}
```

Then I'm configuring the input with one of these sizes.

```
InputConfiguration inputConfiguration = new InputConfiguration(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
```

The I'm passing this input to a capture session

```
cameraDevice.createReprocessableCaptureSession(inputConfiguration, Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
        try {
            cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, handler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Camera Preview Failed!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, null);
```

And, I'm also getting an

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input size 1920x1080 is not valid
```

error, though this size is supported on my phone camera (from the debug result of `getOutputSizes()`).

So, my question is on my approach and where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse [getOutputSizes(imageFormat)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputSizes(int)) with [getInputSizes(imageFormat)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getInputSizes(int)). Note that you must check separately that the format is supported for input or output.

Comment: Now how to send parameters to getOutputSizes(), like I have to get values from a spinner and then give two attributes height and width to output configuration and use this to createCaptureSessionByOutputConfigurations(), in some way and display the picture of the selected resolutions. How do I send these output params, the documentation only makes it tougher.

Comment: This is not easily documented, becasue in most cases we can rely on the default behavior. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, making a small camera application, there's a spinner having all the supported output resolutions , the user gets to choose from the spinner and these params are set to the camera to get an output image having the selected user resolution. Well, this is my project or else I could just have used a GitHub thingy or some default mobile camera app.

Comment: IMHO, there is very little value in choosing output size for preview images.

Comment: Well I found out that I could just save the image in whatever way, and then just save it in a specific resolution using Bitmap and compress it, then save it.